# Cant add file icon image to xib image view programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I am trying to add file icon image to xib image view for collectionView. I can only use dynamic label that changes in xib, but the image is not showing up at all. Here we can see how I have connected outlets - Text Field, Image View to Object Label Collection View Item. [image: On the right you can see the outlets connected]

[image: Here you can see the image view.]

So, the label is showing up correctly, but the image is not. You can see it here.[image: Image is not appearing anywhere]

And finally the code. Everything what I need is happening in this part of code. You can see how I changed dynamically the label, but why I can't get file icon from file path I don't know. filesList array is a list of file/folder paths in some directory.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return filesList.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

  let cell = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "LabelCollectionViewItem",for: indexPath)

    for i in 0..<filesList.count {
      let test = filesList[i]

      let fileIcon = NSWorkspace.shared().icon(forFile: test.path)
      print(test)

      cell.textField?.stringValue = "test"

      cell.imageView?.image =  fileIcon

    }

    return cell

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Here you can see all my code - https://pastebin.com/xF12Kzdq

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on the `cell.imageView?.image =  fileIcon` line and run your project.
Once you hit the breakpoint, investigate the values of your objects to see if they are nil or if the got wrong values. What could be wrong? cell.imageView is nil, test.path is wrong, fileIcon is nil, etc. It also might be a sandbox issue (see the console for violation warnings).

You can inspect variable values in the “Variables View” or by typing something like `po fileIcon` in the Xcode Console while being stopped at the breakpoint.

Comment: Hello, It looks like there is no problem with variable values. They all are set. The sandbox mode is off. Here you can see the breakpoint output - https://imgur.com/a/OWpgzOo

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Issue was that the imageView in nib file was outside of the actual nib visible screen, so it just did not appear when I ran the application. Thanks for the help!